# Serilog creates the log file but doesn't write into it

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, serilog

So I've started using Serilog withing my ASP .NET Core 3.1 Web API as follows:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>                
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>()
                  .UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) =>
       loggerConfiguration.ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration));
     });
```

However, **the log file gets created**, *but nothing gets written into it*, no matter where I call something like `Log.Debug("Write this")`. I tried using different paths to avoid any writing credential issue of some sort, to no avail. Also, I can't see anything in the Output window of Visual Studio, despite setting a Console log too. Here's what I wrote in my appSettings.json:

```
"Serilog": {
"MinimumLevel": {
  "Default": "Debug"
},
"WriteTo": [      
  {
    "Name": "Console"
  },
  {
    "Name": "File",
    "Args": {
      "path": "log.txt",
      "rollingInterval": "Day",
      "retainedFileCountLimit": 7,
      "buffered": true
    }
  }
]
  },
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Update*: [OP edited the question after my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/61361301/4) below and removed the part o the code that I'm pointing out.

---

In your example above, you are writing to Serilog at the very start of your App, way before Serilog has even been configured, so your messages are just being discarded...

In order to do what you want, you need to set up Serilog first.

Follow the [`EarlyInitializationSample`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore/tree/dev/samples) in the Serilog.AspNetCore repo to see how it's done, which looks something like this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Serilog;

namespace EarlyInitializationSample
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; } = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production"}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();

        public static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .WriteTo.Debug()
                .WriteTo.Console(
                    outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj} {Properties:j}{NewLine}{Exception}")
                .CreateLogger();

            try
            {
                Log.Information("Getting the motors running...");

                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

                return 0;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
                return 1;
            }
            finally
            {
                Log.CloseAndFlush();
            }
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                })
                .UseSerilog();
    }
}
```

---

> ### [Debugging and Diagnostics](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics)
>
> When Serilog is not behaving as you expect, this may be caused by an internal exception or configuration issue. [Here are a couple of ways to sort things out](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics).

Comment: Sorry, that's only one point of the many I've placed Serilog in the code. It doesn't log anything no matter where. Is your answer original code written by you or does it come from a doc?

Comment: @StackLloyd The code above is from the EarlyInitializationSample linked in the answer

Comment: @StackLloyd You might want [enable SelfLog and check for any exceptions](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics) happening in Serilog.

Comment: Why "messages are just being discarded" ? And what do you mean by "are writing to Serilog at the very start of your App"? How do you know where OP write to Serilog? In the example, OP just integrate Serilog, but not write logs using it.

Comment: @Chebur Writing to a Serilog logger is supposed to be a safe operation and never throw exceptions, by design. You can read more on the [Reliability](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Reliability) docs. That means if an error occurs when writing a log, the message will be lost, unless the sink has a mechanism to try again later (a.k.a. Durable sink). The sinks the OP is using in the example are _not_ durable.

Comment: @Chebur [The OP was writing to Serilog in the very first line of code of the Main method](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/61361301/4), but unfortunately they've edited their question **after** I posted my answer and removed it.

Comment: This answer actually worked. Now there's another issue I'd like to solve, thus I'll open another question. Thank you.